# How to Destroy Application on Exit Button J2me

Tags: java-me, exit, symbian, nokia

i want to destroy my app instance on Exit Button (RED KEY) in Nokia phone.
any help .?

Answer (score 1):

`DestroyApp` is called when App is closing.you can request to destroy App by calling `notifyDestroyed()` in `DestroyApp()` method of application life cycle.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dosen't J2ME Game/App terminate on pressing the the Red Key?

You're App will be destroyed once you press the red key (End Call Key).As far as I know,all Nokia mobiles terminate it.In s40 phones it shows a "Exit Application?" message while on s60 phones,it will terminate instantly.